# if it's correct remove a class in the dom using ClassName?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

in the following element to remove class='nav':

```
<p class="nav">I am Div1</p>
var p = document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0];
```

i know that i can remove it using

```
p.classList.remove("nav")
```

But can i use Use :

```
p.className = "".
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Thank you, but i already know the answer, i just want to know if this answer  p.className = "". is correct or not

Comment: It depends on your goal. `className = ''` will remove ***all*** classes on the element, not just one specific one. If that's your goal, then it will work. If you want to remove a single class then you'll need `.classList.remove('foo')`

Comment: So if i use p.className = "", it will remove all classes names in paragraphs ?

Comment: You can easily know the answer to this by trying out the statement in your code

Comment: "Can I use..." - what happens when you try it?

Comment: @freedomn-m well nothing, that's why am asking. it's my first time using and learning dom so ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p.className='';` works perfectly as long as you want to **remove all classes**. 
Otherwise use **classList.remove**

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var p = document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0];
    p.classList.remove('nav');
});
```

```css
.nav { background: red }
```

```html
<p class="nav">I am Div1</p>
<button id ='btn'>Remove
```

Answer (score 1):

with JQuery:

```
$('.nav').removeClass('nav');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it using `element.classList.remove()` in JavaScript

```
document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0].classList.remove("nav");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
p.classList.remove("env");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove it like this:

```
p.classList.remove('class1')
```